# Rails - generate "flash" like modal from controller

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am confusing about how to make a popup windows (modal) to tell the user when something is happened after a controller action. This should be something like the `flash[:notice/alert]` function that use in `redirect_to` or `render`.

I have found a gem called 'server-generated-popup' but I don't really understand how to use it or whether it suits my case or not.

I have also tried to use magnific-popup and bootstrap-popup, but they seems to more likely generate popup/modal by user's actions (click a button, click a link). I have tried to use them by `render :template` to create a modal but with no luck.

What I want to do is really the same as `flash[:notice/alert]`, but replace it to a modal that no user inputs are needed. What should I do? My thought is:

1. Create a new flash type by `add_flash_types :modal`
2. replace the behavior of it with some code to bootstrap modal (should be the easier than magnificent popup?)
3. call it in `render` or `redirect_to`

But how to do the step two?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try doing

```
render js: 'alert("popup")'
```

This way you can trigger modal popup from the server

Another way is to render the flash yourself. In your application layout you can do something like this:

```
<% flash.each do |k, v| %>
   <% if k == :mocal_alert %>
     <script>alert("popup");</script>
   <% else %>
      <# how ever you are rendering the default flashes %>
      <div id="<%= k %>"><%= v %></div>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Obviously replace `alert("popup")` with something nicer.